# VSTO Outlook Add-in Move folders up and down

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

i have an outlook add-in in which a folder is selected.Now what i want is, i want to move the folder up and down using C#. Is there someone that can help me in this case. You help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the `PR_SORT_POSITION` Extended MAPI property using `MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`. You can see that property (if the  particular folder was manually reordered) in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMAPIFolder button). 
See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2013/11/08/mapi-provider-sorting/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can not. Non-default folders are sorted alphabetically.